# How to make UDF, for a descriptive analysis of all variables in a data frame

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I have a database with hundreds of variables, of different classes: int, factor, logi, date, chr and num, but basically they are factors, a small example would be something like this:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
        A = sample(1:10),
        B = rnorm(10, 25, 12),
        C = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
        H = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 10),
        f1 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
        f2 = sample(letters[4:6], 10, replace = TRUE),
        Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
        W = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, replace = TRUE),
        Z = sample(c("true", "false"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to make a descriptive analysis of each of the variables in the database according to the factors of two varaibles, but as it is logical it is not practical to make the code one by one. I thought about creating a function that would select the data according to the levels of the factors that I want, and then I would do a little descriptive of each one according to the class that is each variable, if it is a factor or character that will apply a function and if it is number or integrate another type of descriptive function.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
MyFunction <-function(df, factor1, factor2, ...){
  # Descriptive analysis of the data frame, according to factor 1 level and factor 2
  #
  # Args:
  #    df: name of the data frame
  #    factor1: group (a, b, c)
  #    factor2: subgroup (d, e, f)
  #
  # Returns: 
  #  
  dat <- filter(df, f1 == factor1 & f2 == factor2) 
    apply(dat, 2, ifelse(is.factor == TRUE | is.character == TRUE, describe,
                      ifelse(is.integer == TRUE | is.numeric == TRUE, 
     summary, "other")))
}
```

But I get an error in the class discrimination of the variables and I have not been able to solve it.

```
 Error in is.factor == TRUE : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

This is the best way that has occurred to me to solve this task, but just as someone can think of a much better or can provide solutions, suggestions or ideas.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It would be good if you could add an example of what you would like the output too look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` can be a little tricky.  The third argument needs to be a *function* that takes a column and does some processing on it.  However, the expression you've given:

```
ifelse(is.factor == TRUE | is.character == TRUE, describe,
    ifelse(is.integer == TRUE | is.numeric == TRUE, summary,
      "other")))
```

isn't a function.  It's just an expression that contains several errors, because `is.factor`, for example, can't be compared with `TRUE`.  It needs to be applied to something first (i.e., the column) to get a boolean that you can then compare.

Instead, you'll want to write something like this:

```
MyFunction <-function(df, factor1, factor2, ...){
  dat <- filter(df, f1 == factor1 & f2 == factor2)
  apply(dat, 2, function(x) {
    if (is.factor(x) | is.character(x))
      describe(x)
    else if (is.numeric(x))
      summary(x)
    else "other"
  })
}
```

which when called with:

```
> MyFunction(dat, "b", "d")
```

gets a little bit closer to what you're looking for.

Unfortunately, there's a another problem.  `apply` is a legacy function that's used for matrices.  When it's used with a data frame, it has a nasty habit of converting it to a matrix (which has all elements of the same type).  In this case, it converts the whole thing into a character matrix, and even the numeric values get treated as characters/factors.

Fortunately, there's another legacy function, called `lapply` that works for data frames and doesn't transform the columns to different types.  So, if you write:

```
MyFunction <-function(df, factor1, factor2, ...){
  dat <- filter(df, f1 == factor1 & f2 == factor2)
  lapply(dat, function(x) {
    if (is.factor(x) || is.character(x))
      describe(x)
    else if (is.numeric(x)) {
      summary(x)
    } else "other"
  })
}
```

you'll finally get the output you want:

```
> MyFunction(dat, "b", "d")
$A
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       2       3       3       4       5 
...

$H
[1] "other"

$f1
x 
       n  missing distinct    value 
       2        0        1        b 

Value      b
Frequency  2
Proportion 1
...
```

If you're using `library(tidyverse)`, then you could replace `lapply` with `map` -- they do the same thing here, but `map` is the more modern function.